# Uso de variables con magic cells SQL en Jupyter

Tags: sql, oracle, jupyter

Estoy haciendo pruebas con Oracle y Jupyter mediante la extensión sql

La verdad es que estoy encantado pero me he encontrado con un problema que no consigo resolver: la utilización de variables dentro de la consulta SQL.

Tengo una variable creada del siguiente modo:

```
v = %sql SELECT idcentro from centros WHERE idce = 2021 and CODIGOREGISTRO = 'xxxxxx'
```

ahora querría hacer algo así:

```
%%sql
SELECT IDPLANTILLA, FROM plantilla
WHERE IDCENTRO = :v
```

Si sustituyo v por su valor la consulta da lo que quiero, pero si no da error.

¿Cómo se puede hacer la llamada utilizando esa variable calculada para que funcione?

Answer (score 0):

Después de muchas vueltas he visto que el problema es que no sabía leer la variable porque el tipo de datos no era el que esperaba.

Para probarlo he hecho lo siguiente:

```
v = %sql select 1054 from dual
type(v)
```

El resultado obtenido es el siguiente:

```
sql.run.ResultSet
```

Haciendo lo siguiente:

```
c = v[0][0]
```

Ya me ha dejado utilizarlo en un SQL del siguiente modo

```
%sql SELECT IDPLANTILLA
 FROM MOLPLANTILLA 
WHERE  ID= :c
```